# KSH runs Java with arguments in variable

Tags: java, variables, arguments, ksh

I need to run Java from KSH script after getting a list of files in a directory as the arguments for running that Java class.

```
cd /batch/App/
find /batch/files/ -type f -print -name "*.xls" >> $list_of_files
/usr/java14/bin/java ConvertApp $list_of_files
```

in which i think it will function like `/usr/java14/bin/java ConvertApp test1.xls test2.xls test3.xls`

But it seems that the argument passing for Java was not successful. Anyone have any idea for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#Examples).

Try this

```
find /batch/files/ -type f -print -name "*.xls" | xargs /usr/java14/bin/java ConvertApp
```

Comment: Won't this run the app once for each file, with that file as the argument?

Comment: No, that's the point with `xargs`. It puts all files as one long string of arguments.

Comment: ...unless you tell it to do them one at a time. By the way, I would recommend using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`

Comment: Ooo. Thats a neat trick. didn't know `xargs` had the `-0` thingy too. Nice indeed.

Comment: By the way, the Unix system that I used currently doesn't seem to support `-print0` ... is there another workaround to deal with filenames that contain space? like double quoting each file name `java ConvertExcel "sample 55.xls" "abc.xls"`

Comment: @Tsubasa: See my answer. Using an array may be the only way. Does your `find` have `-printf`?

Answer (score 1):

`find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` is the way to go.

The answers that recommend `cat` or a variable will fail if there are spaces in any filenames. If you don't want to use `xargs`, you can have a better chance of success if you use an array:

```
saveIFS=$IFS IFS=$'\n'
files=($(find...))
IFS=$saveIFS
java ... "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems.

1. `find` outputs matches one per line, you need to convert this so they are space delimited, perhaps by using sed or awk.
2. You should probably put the output into a variable, using;

   `list_of_files = 'find ........'`

then call java with

```
java ConvertApp ${list_of_files}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the `.xls` files found by `find` command into the file `$list_of_files`.

Next you want to send the contents of this file as command line argument to your java program. To do that you can use command substitution as:

```
/usr/java14/bin/java ConvertApp "$(cat $list_of_files)"
```

or

```
/usr/java14/bin/java ConvertApp "`cat $list_of_files`"
```